# Перенос из одной базы в другую java

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle

Имеется база данных на Oracle и на Postgres, необходимо средствами java выгрузить нужные таблицы и распределить их в таблицы в Postgres, то бишь маграцию некоторых данных обеспечить. Как подключиться вроде понял, а как сделать сначала экспорт из oracle, а потом импорт в postgres не до конца понимаю.

```
public class ConnectToOracle {
    final private static String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static String url;
    final private static String server = "";
    final private static String port = "";
    final private static String sid = "";
    final private static String username = "";
    final private static String password = "";
    private static Connection connection;
    private static boolean isConnected = false;
    /*private static Statement stmt;
    private static ResultSet rs;*/

    private static boolean connect() {
        try {
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + server + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
            System.out.println(url);
            Class.forName(driverName);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("connecting: " + url);
            if(connection.equals(null))
                isConnected = false;
            else
                isConnected = true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
            isConnected = false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException\n" + e.getMessage());
            isConnected = false;
        }
        return isConnected;
    }
}
```

буду благодарен за любые объяснения! заранее благодарю!

Comment: Разбиваем задачу на части.
1. Подключение (это есть).
2. Получение списка таблиц.
3. Получение структуры таблицы для каждой таблицы из пункта 2.
4. Получение списка индексов для таблицы.
5. Формирование запроса на чтение данных пачками по N строк из целевой таблицы.
6. Формирование запроса для создания целевой таблицы в целевой базе (именно таблицы, пока не вставка данных).
7. Формирование запроса на вставку данных в целевую таблицу, в соответствии с набором полей из таблицы-источника и их типом.
8. Чтение данных из источника.
9. Вставка пачки данных после чтения в целевую таблицу.

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы все же какой-то пример кода тоже посмотреть...не до конца понятно

Comment: Вот пример https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html .
Кратко: с помощью объекта соединения подготваливаем запрос методом `createStatement` или подобным (есть несколько методов для подготовки запроса). В запрос передаём данные или сразу исполняем (в зависимости от того, нужны нам параметры в запросе или нет).
Далее, получаем объект результата: ResultSet. Из этого объекта можно получить данные различных типов (Вот тут http://dmivic.chat.ru/JDBC/mapping.doc.html про типы данных и их соответствия в пункте 8.6.1 и ниже).

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!!!